# Vim: error reading input

Tags: bash, shell, vim, zsh

I've already searched about this error, but I couldn't find a solution.

I'm following a basic guide to join the Linux world, and I'm trying to create a `.txt` file, adding some text lines in Vim using that script. It should work, but not in my case.

Here my simple script (I'm using `zsh`, if it could be an important information):

```
#!/bin/sh

filename= test.txt
vim $filename << COMMAND
i
Hello
^[
:x
COMMAND
```

The script fails with message: `Vim: error reading input`.

Where did I am wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a typo (an extra space) in the assignment to `filename` variable: `filename= test.txt`. This expression is interpreted as *calling `test.txt` command with `filename` environment variable which is set to an empty string*. So you should remove the space after `=`.

Regarding the *Error reading input* message, read the Vim documentation: `:help E208`:

> ```
> Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
> ```
>
> This occurs when Vim cannot read typed characters while input is required. Vim got stuck, the only thing it can do is exit.  This can happen when both stdin and stderr are redirected and executing a script that doesn't exit Vim.

So Vim thinks it read a script that didn't exit Vim. Your script enters the insert mode, enters `Hello`, then <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and finally calls the `:x` command. Everything is good, and the `:x` command exits Vim, if it is entered in the command line area, of course. If you had entered `^[` as <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the script would have exited the insert mode and executed the `:x` command successfully. Therefore, you entered `^[` as two characters. So your real input was `Hello^[:x` (and the script hadn't exited Vim):

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

Now if you replace the two characters `^[` with the actual escape character, and execute the script from the same directory, it will fail because of a swap file:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

(you can read a long description by running `vim test.txt`). You can ignore swap files with `-n` option: `vim -n "$filename"`. Now the output will be:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

It makes sense. You actually don't need the interactive version of Vim. So you should use the *ex mode* (`-e` option), or rather *improved ex mode* (`-E` option): `vim -n -E "$filename"`.

It is also a good idea to wrap the values in single quotes, if the content is not supposed to be interpreted, and in double quotes, if the string contains shell variables: `filename='test.txt'`.

The fixed version:

```sh
filename='test.txt'
vim -n -E "$filename" << COMMAND
i
Hello
^[
:x
COMMAND
```

(`^[` is entered in Vim using <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll put all of this into my head :D

Comment: I was able to insert the unicode ESC character in place of `^[`

Comment: How could I issue a command to move the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

I try the example above and I found that for the ex mode of vim `vim -e` or `vim -E`, you should add a '.' when you think the insert is finish or it will not work. The code is as the follow. `^[` is `Ctrl-V Esc`

```
#!/bin/sh

filename='test.txt'
vim -n -E "$filename" << COMMAND
i
Hello
.
^[
:x
COMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the space in `filename= test.txt`, and check that you do not have spaces after the last line with `COMMAND`. When you want to have Hello on the first line, remove the name line after the `i`: `iHello^[`.

Did you enter `^[` with `CTRL-v ESC`? It must be one character.

Comment: Thanks man! i wrote the `^[` using the 2 characters. I've to learn better Vim commands too :)

Comment: Than you can accept the answer. I have used the here-construction for editing files a lot, but I switched to `sed -i`. For interactive editing I am still using vi(m).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=test.txt

coms="iHello world^[:x ${filename}^M"
vim -c "normal $coms"
```

As Walter A said, you have to replace `^[` and `^M` by hitting respectively `Ctrl-V Esc` and `Ctrl-V Return` inside the `coms` variable.

See `man vim`, and in Vim `:h :normal` for more help.